# how to map SampleCount property using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables - Run and Sample, where Sample.RunId is a foreign key linking samples to their runs.

I would like to have a SampleCount property in Run, which is the number of Sample objects associated with the particular Run.

Is it possible to map such a property in NHibernate mapping of the Run type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the collection solution by Diego Mijelshon is perfectly valid it does mean an extra query after fetching the `Run` entity. If you haven't mapped the collection and you do not want to or you do not want the additional query, consider a "computed" property as such

in the `Run` class mapping

```
<property name="SamplesCount" type="long" formula="(select count(s.Id) from Samples s where s.RunId = Id)" />
```

and in the class `Run` just add

```
long SamplesCount {get; set;}
```

Note that in the query, for the part "s.RunId = Id" NHibernate will insert the proper alias for the root table. Also, don't forget the parenthesis, it makes it easier for the parser and in some cases is required.

This approach has the benefit of applying a subquery on the select (which may or may not be good depending on your case). The property can also be lazily-loaded (i think a NH 2++ feature) if this property is something you will only rarely need.

Comment: Good one, I hadn't got formulas referencing the current entity right before. BTW, lazy-loaded properties are new to NH 3.x, so you can only use them now if you are willing to reference the trunk version.

Comment: Sounds great. I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: interesting, in 2.1.2GA the mapping validates for property laziness although its not actually done

Answer (score 1):

While you can do that using a `<join>`, it's not a good idea.

Instead, declare your `Run.Samples` collection as `lazy="extra"`, and accessing `Run.Samples.Count` will do a query for the count instead of loading the entire collection.

Comment: <join> creates issues when updating, and you're also loading extra data on every access to Run. It's a hack to use it in this context (not that I haven't done it...)